# MySQL Junction Table Foreign Keys

Tags: mysql, sql, database, junction-table

I have several tables: `company`, `customer`, `company_has_customer`, and `transaction`.

`company_has_customer` is a many-to-many junction table using the PKs of `company` and `customer` as its PK.

In almost all situations throughout the database, both the `company` and `customer` are used to identify a record (e.g. in the `transaction` table).

My question is whether I should create the foreign key in the `transaction` table to point to `company_has_customer` or to the two tables (`company`, `customer`) individually?

I believe it would be best for referential integrity to send those FKs through `company_has_customer` to ensure that `transaction` records are only inserted if there is a relationship between the company and the customer.  Are there any standards or conventions to support my hunch?

Comment: SO isn't really appropriate for opinionated design discussions.

Comment: Thanks Barmar, I modified the question to be less opinionated.  I'm really looking for best-practices in this type of situation, but I've got strong hunches.

Comment: Maybe you'll have better luck over at dba.stackexchange.com.

Comment: I knew stackoverflow felt a little wrong, I forget that there is a giant network of sites for these things.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how to think about the problem.  Does the transaction have a separate relationship to company and customer?  Or, is the transaction specific to the company/customer relationship forever?

I would guess the first is the case.

The specific situation to think about is:  what happens if the relationship between a customer and a company changes *after* the transaction takes place?  Does the transaction retain the original company or does it switch to the new company?  Or is it invalidated?

If you reference the `company_has_customer` table, then the relationship might just disappear.  In fact, you probably want the relationships to remain as they were when the transaction occurred, so go for two foreign key relationships.

Comment: The relationship between company and customer exists in many proposed tables.  Essentially the data between customer and company will always belong to that company/customer combination.  Enough so that it may even be simpler to add a FK to the customer table with the owning company ID. M2M just ensures some level of future options.

Comment: @KyleJohnson . . . In that case, the relationship is to `customer` and you can look up the company from there.

Comment: Yeah, it's just up in the air where the real boundary lies.  I envision that some customers may belong to multiple companies, or that multiple companies may manage the same customers.  It's hard to work in all the little details like that.